# renderArgs is null in template in play! framework

Tags: groovy, playframework, template-engine

I have a controller function like this

```
public static void renderCustomersList() {
        System.out.println("renderArgs"+renderArgs.toString());
        render(renderArgs);
    }
```

In my groovy template

renderArgs ${renderArgs.toString()}

I have renderArgs with value printed in my console but when i pass to the template its printing as null. I wanted those values in my main.html. I printed renderArgs in Both my renderCustomersList.html and main.html  the values were null on both templates. What could be the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to pass `renderArgs` as a parameter to the `render` function - all the variables in the `renderArgs` scope will be available in the template anyway. But instead of accessing the `renderArgs` object itself in the template, go for the independent values instead - see below.

Controller:

```
public static void renderCustomersList() {
    ... // some code to initialize yourVariable
    renderArgs.put("yourVariable", yourVariable);
    render(); // renderArgs not needed as a parameter
}
```

And in the template:

```
${yourVariable}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note also that you don't have to user `renderArgs` if you don't want to.  You can also pass some parameters to `render()` like this:

```
public static void renderCustomersList() {
    ...
    render(customers, products, foobar); 
}
```

and then you can get at those parameters in your template with the variable names:

```
#{list items:customers, as:cust}
...
Foobar: ${foobar}
```

The only case in which you *need* to use `renderArgs` is if you want to use different names for your parameters in the template than in the controller.  This is potentially confusing though, so I try not to do it.

Comment: I find the implicit method rather confusing. For instance, I learned the hard way that `String message = getMessage(); render(message);` is in no way equivalent to `render(getMessage());`, since the latter does not put a `message` item into `renderArgs`. Thus, I tend to prefer the explicit `renderArgs.put("message", getMessage()); render();`

Comment: Oh for sure, I feel like the entire idiom probably breaks some principle of programming. I can't think of what it would be called, but I'm uncomfortable with the disconnect between the variable names in the controller and those in the template. Spring uses the `put("message", getMessage())` idiom, and I'm not convinced that it's much better, but it is more flexible for sure. I'd be more comfortable if there were some way to constrain what parameter names get passed to the template, used in the template, or both, but I don't think that's possible. I just do it this way for brevity.